# Label Propagation in networks using Scikit and networkx

Tags: python, pandas, graph, scikit-learn, networkx

I have never used label propagation before, neither in Python, but now I would need to check if this can be suitable for my problem.
I have a dataset like the following

```
User                    Connection               Score
        xxx.dean.martin       vera.miles           10
        xxx.dean.martin       christopher.sole     5     
        xxx.dean.martin       elis.con             NaN    
        xxx.catherine.rice    vera.miles           NaN
        xxx.vera.miles        NaN                  0
```

where `Score` depends only to `User` and can take values 0, 5, or 10.
I would like to build a graph where `Users` are nodes and `Connection` are the targets. This means that, for example, `xxx.dean.martin`   is linked to    `vera.miles`. `Score` should be a value assigned to the node (e.g., `xxx.dean.martin`).
As shown in the example, since some values is missing (NaN), I would like to use label propagation to assign `Scores` where they are missing. Looking at the last example,

```
      `xxx.vera.miles        NaN                0.0`
```

I should expect links between `vera.miles, dean.martin` and `catherine.rice`, when I visualise that in a network. Based on neighbor, I would like to assign ('transfer'/'propagate') the score value through the nodes.

Example of output as dataset (that should come from a graph visualization):

```
 User                    Connection               Score
            xxx.dean.martin       vera.miles         10
            xxx.dean.martin       christopher.sole   5
            xxx.dean.martin       elis.con           5  # just the average of the nodes which User is linked with   
            xxx.catherine.rice    vera.miles         0
            xxx.vera.miles        NaN                0
```

Comment: I'm confused about the network, and what is it that you're supposed to propagate on it. It looks to me that the network itself is between users (`vera.miles` and appears in both `User` and `Connection`), they're connected by the value in `Net_value` (the weights, are these symmetric? is it a directed network?). Now, it looks like the labels are also users, and here's where my confusion starts. Maybe you'd be better off with a matrix completion algorithm?

Comment: Hi torresmateo, yeah, unfortunately it is not easy to explain how the network looks like, but I will try it.  Both users and connections are nodes in my network. Specifically, Connection is the target. Not all the fields have values. However, some nodes can be already connected to another one, even if the Connection field is empty (NaN) as in the case of xxx.vera.miles which is actually connected with xxx.catherine.rice. But this could be easily visualise in the network, once built. The problem, however,is in the Score. Some Users have no score but they may be connected with nodes that have it

Comment: I would like then to find a way to 'transfer' or 'propagate' this information. I would say that one way could be to take the average of scores of nodes which are connected to the node with the missing score. There might be also this label propagation that, from what I read, it can be also used. It would be ok for answering this question just showing how to get missing score values. I would prefer by using Label Propagation, but it could be also good any other approach ;)

Comment: I tried to make the example easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the setting you're posing, this is not the standard setting for label propagation, since the nodes and the meaning of the labels are somehow mixed.

To get you expected output via a 1-step propagation that calculates the mean, you can simply do:

```py
df.fillna(df.groupby('User', as_index=False).mean()).fillna(0)
```

which will fill the `NaN` with the mean, and the leftover `NaN` with `0`.